# package manager odd behavior after ubuntu failed update wich included an nginx update

Tags: apt, dpkg, nginx

So, yesterday I updated ubuntu and that included an nginx update, the process warned about diffs/changes to the `default` file under `sites-available`, I reviewed the changes and prepared a new file which included the updates and my personal settings, I noticed the default directory to store projects was now `/var/www/html/` instead of `/usr/share/nginx/html/` and I actually had been thinking about making that very same change myself so I agreed and included that change in my new `default` configuration file, which I saved to `~/Desktop` temporarily, so I wouldn't interfere with the update process.

After I was finished editing my new file I agreed to replace the existing one as asked by the update prompt/process.
The updating process continued only to state a failure a few seconds later, the error stated something about `failed to decompress package`, I thought it would be fixed by attempting to update the system again so I tried but the update manager stated "there are no updates to install" (needless to say I got a bit suspicious but well, I just restarted the OS as asked).
After rebooting I backed up and replaced the `default` file with my newly created one and moved all contents of `/usr/share/nginx/html/` to `/var/www/html/`
Oddly enough, going to `localhost` didn't work but going to any other project stored on subdirectories worked fine, so I didn't care too much for the moment.

Here's where it gets interesting (well a bit interesting, at least).
Today I installed a non related package and suddenly the package manager tried to include some nginx changes in the process by executing a script and failed to do so.
[image: gif of package manager tty process showing the previously stated error]

NOTE: Here's a pastebin of the terminal's output (before and after the fix):
http://pastebin.com/pYv7yKrz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed this line:

```
cp: cannot stat `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html': No such file or directory`
```

So I figured maybe just adding the previous index.html file (located now on `/var/www/html/`) to the old path (`/usr/share/nginx/html/`) would help the script execute without throwing an exception, and it did work.
[image: gif of package manager tty process showing the previously stated success]

`http://localhost` is working fine now.
[image: nginx's default welcome message showing on browser]

Comment: I'm glad you solved your own problem. However, please do not add a new question to this answer thread. Instead, ask a new question and link this one for relevance. Thank you!

Comment: that's exactly what I did